# Putting checkbox values into a txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement, checkbox, fwrite

```
<input id="c1"type="checkbox" name="cq1" value="value1" >


extract($_REQUEST);
$file=fopen("standard.txt","a");

fwrite($file, "Value: \n");

if ($_GET['cq1'] == 'value1') {
    fwrite($file,"Done\n");
    }

fclose($file);
```

I've been trying to get my checkbox values into a txt file but I think somethings wrong with my if statment and I can't find the problem. All the other fwriting works but I think it's something with my checkboxes.

Comment: if fill checked in checkbox then only $_GET['cq1'] will exist else this variable will not exist.

Comment: Can you explain what this means and how i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  check box: 
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="my_vechicle" value="Bike">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <p>if you check this check box, then only <b><q>my_vehicle</q></b> variable will exist in $_GET[] variable (like this, $_GET['my_vechicle']) else this variable will not appear.</p>
</form>
```